# spring data elastic search log issue

Tags: elasticsearch, spring-data, spring-data-elasticsearch

I am trying to connect to **Elastic Search 5.4.2** .

I am using **spring-data-elasticsearch 3.0.0.M4**.

I get the below exception when i connect to the elastic search instance

```
Exception in thread "main" NoNodeAvailableException[None of the configured nodes are available: [{#transport#-1}{ZJchkKLgRUGzjUP_cG7z9g}{102.21.31.52}{102.21.31.52}]]
at org.elasticsearch.client.transport.TransportClientNodesService.ensureNodesAreAvailable(TransportClientNodesService.java:348)
    at org.elasticsearch.client.transport.TransportClientNodesService.execute(TransportClientNodesService.java:246)
    at org.elasticsearch.client.transport.TransportProxyClient.execute(TransportProxyClient.java:59)
    at org.elasticsearch.client.transport.TransportClient.doExecute(TransportClient.java:366)
    at org.elasticsearch.client.support.AbstractClient.execute(AbstractClient.java:408)
    at org.elasticsearch.client.support.AbstractClient.execute(AbstractClient.java:397)
    at org.elasticsearch.client.support.AbstractClient$IndicesAdmin.execute(AbstractClient.java:1250)
    at org.elasticsearch.client.support.AbstractClient$IndicesAdmin.exists(AbstractClient.java:1272)
```

I used to get similair error when i was working with  lower versions of Elastic Search ( 2.3.3 ) . Mostly it would be related to incompatible version of elastic search and spring data elastic search

I would like to view the logs in order to know the root cause of the error.

I am not able to enable logs for org.elasticsearch package.

If I configure the log4j.xml , I am able to view the spring data logs but elastic search logs are not showing up ? Has anybody faced similar issue ?

I was browsing through the elastic search source code and could not find much logger statements ( esp . in org.elasticsearch.client.transport ) . Do they have minimal log statements ?

Comment: Do you find the answer?

Comment: I could find only limited logging from spring data elastic search. Elastic Search server supports extensive logging. You can view the error log from the elastic search console . Also logging of all queries hitting ES in JSON format is also available